# why are custom objects hashable (and usable in dict) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newbie question: in order for an object to be used as a key in `dict` it needs to be hashable. It's clear that immutable types can be used as keys while mutable types cannot. However, if I define a class which is mutable, apparently it can still be used as a key. In the code below `my_obj` is a reference to a memory slot containing an object of type `RandomObject`. That memory slot contains a reference (`x`) to 25 but this reference can be changed to point to anything else. This is confusing for me, why does it work? Moreover, `my_obj` can be made to reference an entirely new instance of `RandomObject`. If hashing occurs on the actual object (and not the memory address of the reference) how can this work?

```
class RandomObject:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

d = {"hi": 1, "bye": 2}
my_obj = RandomObject(25)
d[my_obj] = 3
print(d)
#{'hi': 1, 'bye': 2, <__main__.RandomObject object at 0x0000000005B75D30>: 3}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your class inherits `object.__eq__` and `object.__hash__`, which work by identity. Hashing doesn't directly care about mutability; it only cares about mutability that affects `==` comparisons. When `==` is by identity, no mutation will affect `==` comparisons.

Comment: i see so it must be the case that things like `list` define their own `__eq__` which compares things inside the list by value as opposed to the actual identity of the list itself? ie why would mutable types not be hashable then

Comment: @Alex: `list.__eq__` does not work by identity. `list` equality comparisons are affected by mutation, so lists prohibit hashing.

Comment: makes sense. is it generally true, then, that all mutable types define their own `__eq__` and hence break hashing? just tested that if i overload `__eq__` in my class it also won't hash

Comment: The next level is that nothing stops you from defining a custom `__hash__` on a mutable class. This is Python after all.